# Have the builder VIPs been removed?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Since the recent update (and really even earlier, though I hadn't been playing much), I haven't seen a single builder VIP (the ones which reduce building time by 3 hours). Does anyone know if they've been specifically removed, or am I just unlucky?

Comment: I have not seen them as of yet, but this doesn't mean they've been removed.  In the past it has often been days between seeing them!

Comment: I've been playing quite consistently to get medals and haven't seen them since the update, either.  Though, as David says, that doesn't mean they're gone, just likely reduced in regularity.

Answer (score 2):

The worker VIPs are still there, they are just far more infrequent since the latest updates, bit unfortunate since new levels are now available so it would be wise to save them if you see them.

Answer (score 0):

No,they have not.

The reason I say this is if you buy a random VIP on the arrivals level, you can still see the Worker VIP swirling around in the mix.  Therefore, you can still receive one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen one in a while, since the new update, also, despite playing more than usual to try to get the Imperial Marches level.  Definitely the distribution of VIPs has changed- I am seeing many more "Big Spenders" and "Upgraders" than before, apparently at the expense of the "Worker" ones.

Answer (score 0):

Their frequency is less than 1:100...because I haven't seen one in over 200 VIPs. Statistically, I'm closing in on 1:1000 but that's assuming a reasonable standard deviation, their bell curve has gotten all kinds of funky.
Suffice it to say they're too rare... :(

Answer (score -1):

I have been playing very regularly and usually for two weeks prior to the upgrade and seeing 2-3 a day.  Since the upgrade, I have not seen a single "Worker".  In addition, just the appearance of standard VIPs appears to have greatly reduced.  I was frequently had the arrival stacked with all 5 slots filled with Recruiters or Workers which I would hold on to until a new level was started (for the worked) or completed (for the recruiters).  Now I not seen a single worker in a week and very few recruiters (maybe one a day?)